# Oracle SQL Developer create SDO_GEOMETRY invalid datatype

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-spatial

I am trying to create a spatial database in SQL Developer, which is connected to Oracle 11g Release 2 on AWS.

When I do this

```
CREATE TABLE cola_markets (
mkt_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(32),
shape SDO_GEOMETRY);
```

and compile, I always get this:

```
errormkt_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(32),
shape SDO_GEOMETRY)
Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

It seems that SQL Developer cannot find the `sdo_geometry` datatype. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you using? Try with the latest release of SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

That should work. Are you sure your database does have Oracle Spatial or Oracle Locator installed.

Databases provided on AWS typically don't.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of your database. 
For oracle 12c onwards all of SDO_GEOM package is available to oracle locator users. Thus your should work.
However, in 12c you may need to deinstall spatial part as mentioned here : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_locator.htm#SPATL1433

Comment: This seems more like a comment, and less like an answer. Please expand your answer and thoroughly explain it. see: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens to anyone with oracle spatial or locator or anything needed correctly installed in MDSYS, and it still doesn't work, you can try granting EXECUTE privileges from MDSYS to your user as I read on

https://blog.ronnyegner-consulting.de/category/oracle-in-general/

It worked for us.